# #include <climits> sometimes not needed sometimes needed?

Tags: c++

This works in CLion:

```cpp
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    int min = INT_MAX;
    return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't on udacity where I'm learning C++:
[image]

Why is there a need to add `#include <climits>` in some instances and not in others?

Comment: `<iostream>` might include other `#include`, but you should not rely on that and include correct header to be portable.

Comment: Do note that CLion isn't a compiler. It "works" for whatever C++ compiler you're actually using in the background  (e.g. GCC, Clang, MSVC, ...)

Comment: @heapunderrun If you think this question is already answered elsewhere on this site, you should flag is as a duplicate. That way the target question gets directly linked to this question instead of forcing future visitors to search through the comments (which are transient and may be deleted)

Comment: @Brian61354270 For what it’s worth such comments *also* lead to these questions be linked on the right-hand “Linked” side bar. *Sometimes* this is more appropriate than closing a question as a duplicate.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Agreed, there's a place for both. Probably half of my comments on this site are "Related: <link>" just for that purpose :)

Comment: The compiler is required to accept your program if it includes the correct headers, but not required to reject your program if it doesn't include them. This is an artefact of the ancient header mechanism, which is over half a century old by now.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean @molbdnilo, can you re-explain?

Comment: Use your favorite search engine to look up "C++ transitive includes".

Comment: So `iostream` sometimes include other heads, sometimes not? Are there different versions of `iostream` depending on where C++ was installed?